# DrawerLayout+CoordinatorLayout Leaves Empty Space At The Bottom Of Screen

Tags: android, android-xml

I'm using DrawerLayout+CoordinatorLayout>appbar_layout>RelativeLayout>ToolBar>LinearLayout+Main Nav.

But it leaves an empty space at the bottom of the screen when user scrolls to the bottom of the screen. 
Bottom VIew: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGe8K.png

Here's the XML code I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            >
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
                app:titleTextColor="#FFF"></androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="27sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                android:text="My Title"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                ></TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            ></LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_nav"
        android:layout_width="277dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"></com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Scrolling and DrawerMenu works fine but the issue is that CoordinatorLayout is having some issues as I've set the background color to Black and at the bottom of the screen, a black empty space appears.

Comment: `android:background="#000000"` CoordinatorLayout

Comment: What your Mean..

Comment: for test case increase height here `android:layout_height="170dp"`

Comment: nothing happens